# If the batch_size equals 1 in tf.layers.batch_normalization(), will it works correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

everyone. I am using tensorflow 1.4 to train a model like **U-net** for my purpose. Due to the constraints of my hardware, when training, the **batch_size could only set to be 1 otherwise there will be OOM error.**

Here comes my question. In this case, when the batch_size equals to 1, will the `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` works correctly(saying moving average, moving variance, gamma, beta)? will small batch_size makes it working unstable?

In my work, I set `training=True` **when training**, and `training=False` **when testing**. When training, I use

```
logits = mymodel.inference()
loss = tf.mean_square_error(labels, logits)
updata_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
...

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
                      tf.local_variables_initializer()))
    sess.run(train_op)
    ...
    saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step)
```

when testing, I use:

```
logits = model.inference()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    results = sess.run(logits)
```

Could anyone tell me that am I using this wrong? And how much influence with **batch_size equals to 1** in **tf.layers.batch_normalization()**?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` works with batches of single elements. Doing *batch normalization* on such batches is actually named *instance normalization* (i.e. normalization of a single instance).

@Maxim made a great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48118940/624547) about *instance normalization* if you want to know more. You can also find more theory on the web and in the literature, e.g. [Instance Normalization: The Missing Ingredient for Fast Stylization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08022).

Comment: Thanks! that is greatly helpful!