# keras BatchNormalization axis clarification

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

The keras [`BatchNormalization` layer](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) uses `axis=-1` as a default value and states that the feature axis is typically normalized. Why is this the case?

I suppose this is surprising because I'm more familiar with using something like [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), which would be equivalent to using `axis=0`. This would normalize the features individually.

Is there a reason why samples are individually normalized by default (i.e. `axis=-1`) in keras as opposed to features?

**Edit: example for concreteness**

It's common to transform data such that each feature has zero mean and unit variance. Let's just consider the "zero mean" part with this mock dataset, where each row is a sample:

```
>>> data = np.array([[   1,   10,  100, 1000],
                     [   2,   20,  200, 2000],
                     [   3,   30,  300, 3000]])

>>> data.mean(axis=0)
array([    2.,    20.,   200.,  2000.])

>>> data.mean(axis=1)
array([ 277.75,  555.5 ,  833.25])
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to subtract the `axis=0` mean, as opposed to the `axis=1` mean? Using `axis=1`, the units and scales can be completely different.

Edit 2:

The first equation of section 3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) seems to imply that `axis=0` should be used for calculating expectations and variances for each feature individually, assuming you have an (m, n) shaped dataset where m is the number of samples and n is the number of features.

Edit 3: another example

I wanted to see the dimensions of the means and variances `BatchNormalization` was calculating on a toy dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense, Input


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = pd.get_dummies(iris.target).values

input_ = Input(shape=(4, ))
norm = BatchNormalization()(input_)
l1 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(norm)
output = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(l1)

model = Model(input_, output)
model.compile(Adam(0.01), 'categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

bn = model.layers[1]
bn.moving_mean  # <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization_1/moving_mean:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

The input X has shape (150, 4), and the `BatchNormalization` layer calculated 4 means, which means it operated over `axis=0`.

If `BatchNormalization` has a default of `axis=-1` then shouldn't there be 150 means?

Comment: Using `axis=-1` goes in the direction of the columns, and if each row is a sample, then individual samples would be normalized - no?

Comment: Hmmm, an interpretation difference. I'll just erase my comment.

Comment: i guess here the axis means dimension like in squeeze method https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping

Comment: Hi @Eliethesaiyan I'm not sure I follow, could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202668/keras-batchnormalization-only-works-for-constant-batch-dim-when-axis-0

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The confusion is due to the meaning of `axis` in `np.mean` versus in `BatchNormalization`.

When we take the mean along an axis, we collapse that dimension and preserve all other dimensions. In your example `data.mean(axis=0)` collapses the `0-axis`, which is the vertical dimension of `data`.

When we compute a `BatchNormalization` along an axis, we preserve the dimensions of the array, and we normalize with respect to the mean and standard deviation over *every other axis*. So in your `2D` example `BatchNormalization` with `axis=1` *is* subtracting the mean for `axis=0`, just as you expect. This is why `bn.moving_mean` has shape `(4,)`.

Comment: Hi @Imran yes that's correct; I'm expecting each row to be a sample. I've seen this convention in the past quite extensively so this would be surprising to me. Could you point me to documentation that confirms that each column is a training sample?

Comment: I've added another example in my 3rd edit which is inconsistent with columns as samples. I'd appreciate any input on my findings.

Comment: @trianta2 OK fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: Imran your new answer seems to be consistent with what I'm observing. To extend the question further, assume that I have a 2D input of shape (m, n), and a dataset of shape (b, m, n) where b is the batch size or # of samples. Since I have 2D features now, what would be the appropriate `axis` value for `BatchNormalization` in order to normalize features individually (for both dimensions) across the batch?

Comment: In this case it makes the most sense to flatten the (m,n) inputs to get the desired behavior from BatchNorm. Then you can normalize along a single feature axis.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I was implicitly thinking of a 1D conv scenario, but no matter. So what still doesn't make sense is why `BatchNormalization` has this unique `axis` behavior when other keras functionality seems to match numpy. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/trianta2/2827478f49370f35b7bf2b5519e27430) for example. The axis works as you'd expect in numpy.

Comment: I think `axis` behaves correctly. The point is you only have to specify one axis, similar to `np.mean` in n dimensions. In higher dimensions such as in conv nets it wouldn't make sense to have to specify every other axis instead of just the axis you are normalizing along - that would be redundant. Even in `2D` it makes sense if you think of it as moving in the direction of `axis 1` and normalizing each value based on the statistics from `axis 0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160206/discussion-between-trianta2-and-imran).

Answer (score 19):

I know this post is old, but am still answering it because the confusion still lingers on in Keras documentation. I had to go through the code to figure this out:

1. The axis variable which is documented as being an integer can actually be a list of integers denoting multiple axes. So for e.g. if my input had an image in the NHWC or NCHW formats, provide axis=[1,2,3] if I wanted to perform BatchNormalization in the way that the OP wants (i.e. normalize across the batch dimension only).
2. The axis list (or integer) should contain the axes that you *do not want* to reduce while calculating the mean and variance. In other words it is the complement of the axes along which you want to normalize - quite opposite of what the documentation appears to say if you go by the conventional definition of 'axes'. So for e.g. if your input I was of shape (N,H,W,C) or (N,C,H,W) - i.e. the first dimension was the batch dimension and you only wanted the mean and variance to be calculated across the batch dimension you should supply axis=[1,2,3]. This will cause Keras to calculate mean M and variance V tensors of shape (1,H,W,C) or (1,C,H,W) respectively - i.e. batch dimension would get marginalized/reduced owing to the aggregation (i.e. mean or variance is calculated across the first dimension). In later operations like (I-M) and (I-M)/V, the first dimension of M and V would get broadcast to all of the N samples of the batch.
3. The BatchNorm layer ends up calling tf.nn.moments with axes=(1,) in this example! That's so because the definition of axes in tf.nn.moments is the correct one.
4. Similarly tf.nn.moments calls tf.nn.reduce_mean, where again the definition of axes is the correct one (i.e. opposite of tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization).
5. That said, the BatchNormalization paper suggests normalizing across the HxW spatial map in additon to the batch dimension (N). Hence if one were to follow that advice, then axis would only include the channel dimension (C) because that's the only remaining dimension that you didn't want to reduce. The Keras documentation is probably alluding to this, although it is quite cryptic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't understand this quite well. If I wanted to normalize a list of values, I would take each value in the list and subtract the mean of this same list and divide this difference by the standard deviation of this same list. Why is the batch norm normalization different in that: "The axis list (or integer) should contain the axes that you do not want to reduce while calculating the mean and variance. In other words it is the complement of the axes along which you want to normalize". An example might help show why this normalization is different

Answer (score 10):

if your mini-batch is a matrix ***A*** *mxn*, i.e. ***m*** samples and ***n*** features, the normalization axis should be ***axis=0***. As your said, what we want is to normalize every feature individually, the default ***axis = -1*** in keras because when it is used in the convolution-layer, the dimensions of figures dataset are usually ***(samples, width, height, channal)***, and the batch samples are normalized long the ***channal axis(the last axis)***.