# What is being normalized by Keras/TensorFlow BatchNormalization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

My question is what is being normalized by BatchNormalization (BN).

I am asking, does BN normalize the channels for each pixel separately or for all the pixels together. And does it do it on a per image basis or on all the channels of the entire batch.

Specifically, BN is operating on `X`. Say, `X.shape = [m,h,w,c]`. So with `axis=3`, it is operating on the "c" dimension which is the number of channels (for rgb) or the number of feature maps.

So lets say the `X` is an rgb and thus has 3 channels. Does the BN do the following: (this is a simplified version of the BN to discuss the dimensional aspects.  I understand that gamma and beta are learned but not concerned with that here.)

For each `image=X` in `m`:

1. For each pixel (h,w) take the mean of the associated r, g, & b values.
2. For each pixel (h,w) take the variance of the associated r, g, & b values
3. Do `r = (r-mean)/var`, `g = (g-mean)/var`, & `b = (b-mean)/var`, where r, g, & b are the red, green, & blue channels of `X` respectively.
4. Then repeat this process for the next image in `m`,

In keras, the docs for BatchNormalization says:

> axis: Integer, the axis that should be normalized (typically the features axis).
>
> For instance, after a `Conv2D` layer with `data_format="channels_first"`,
>   set `axis=1` in `BatchNormalization`.

But what is it exactly doing along each dimension?

Comment: BN does mostly work like that. I don't understand the question.

Comment: I am asking, does BN normalize the channels for each pixel separately or for all the pixels together.  And does it do it on a per image basis or on all the channels of the entire batch.

Comment: For each pixel separately, normalized across the batch so the mean and stddev for each pixel in each batch are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

First up, there are several ways to apply batch normalization, which are even mentioned in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167v3.pdf) specifically for convolutional neural networks. See the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38553927/712995), which outlines the difference between a *usual* and *convolutional* BN, and also the reason why both approaches make sense.

Particularly [`keras.layers.BatchNormalization`](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) implements the *convolutional* BN, which means that for an input `[m,h,w,c]`  it computes `c` means and standard deviations across `m*h*w` values. The shapes of the running mean, running std dev and gamma and beta variables are just `(c,)`. The values across spatial dimensions (*pixels*), as well as across the batch, are **shared**.

So a more accurate algorithm would be: for each R, G, and B channel compute the mean/variance across all pixels and all images in this channel and apply the normalization.